Have drugstores stopped doing digital passport photos？
I’ve just been to a Walgreens and a CVS in the US; both told me they can’t take a passport photo and email it to me. They will only print it or put it on a flash drive. Is this a thing? Or did I happen across the two stupidest drugstores in America?

Their store finder claims 'includes a FREE optional digital copy sent to your email ... in most of our 7,750 locations' https://photo.walgreens.com/store/passport-photos

On their website, Walgreens at least claims their photo service 'includes a FREE optional digital copy sent to your email ... in most of our 7,750 locations'
So maybe you were just unlucky to be in one of their branches that doesn't do email. Or the staff isn't yet aware of this option.
I tried to find information about CVS too, but unfortunately the relevant website is not available outside the US.

I've never heard of an email option at any passport photos location in the US. If it exists, from my experience that would be an exception, not the rule. Even thumb drive is new, used to be a CD, or print only even.
Note: I don't have Walgreens anywhere near me, last I needed it I got it from Costco a couple of years ago.

Just an update from the comments:
Apparently it is a thing that's starting to become a norm in the US. The reason, probably, is that the US Department of State is running now a pilot where people can apply for passport renewals online, and would need digital photos for that. So I imagine while Walgreens the chain advertises it, Walgreens the staffers may not yet be aware or well trained for that. It's new.
As online applications for renewals of passports, driving licenses, ids, and whats not, become the norm in the US - this obviously will become a wide-spread service provided by every passport photos shop in the country. Hopefully soon.

And still they (wallgreens) do so, apparently. By email is free, while there is a fee for a USB drive. The relevant cvs page is unavailable outside the US, so I can't check that

@Berend Apparently, I added a note that I don't have any walgreens anywhere nearby to check after seeing your comment. But that would be new, and probably not surprising that maybe even staff is not familiar with that.

I'm guessing e-mail isn't all that popular since most physical passports require physical photos with strict guidelines around them and there is a chance that printing at home will mess them up. For things like Visas and ETAs generally a selfie is good enough so you don't need get a professional picture. Comes down to supply and demand. In addition, e-mailing requires handling personal data which is always an extra head ache for a store.

@Hilmar The US DoS is piloting online passport renewal applications, which I guess why this feature starts showing up, but it would probably take time for a) staff to be aware of it and how to do it, and b) for people to actually ask for it in droves since it's only a very limited pilot right now.

For reference I need this for a visa application which requires a digital and not a paper photo

@TimCampion my last drug store experience for a passport photo was miserable.  I would seriously consider spending the extra money to have it done at a photography studio, especially since foreign requirements often aren't the same as the US requirements.  For a digital photo, I would also seriously consider doing it myself, which would have been quicker, simpler, and cheaper than my aforementioned experience in the drug store.

@Hilmar "most physical passports require physical photos": but the days are long gone when one of the two required copies of the the physical photo was physically fixed to the passport's identification page and the other was presumably filed away in an archive somewhere.  The photo is going to be scanned anyway, and most likely destroyed afterwards.

@phoog The last time I needed a physical passport photo in the US, I the one I brought with me to the embassy was rejected, and they directed me to a photography store that took compliant photos.  The price about the same that I'd paid at some drugstore for the image that was rejected.

The point about sensitivity regarding personal data would make sense to me… except that places like CVS were well ahead of their time in terms of collecting personal data via their member program… it’s hard to imagine them being shy about getting their hands on email data!
